# Do miracles associated with the cause for canonization have to be believed?

Tags: catholicism, saint, miracles

> The requirement of miracles in the causes of canonization are crucial because they are a divine confirmation of the holiness of the person invoked, says a Vatican aide. ([EWTN](https://www.ewtn.com/catholicism/library/why-miracles-are-required-for-canonizations-5992))

Given that these confirmed miracles are causes for public veneration, do the miracles themselves have to be believed? Or are they matters of private revelation (like Marian apparitions, for instance)?

Comment: 2 Thess. 2:9 is a warning about relying on miracles and signs to determine holiness.

Comment: @MikeBorden it may be a warning but it doesn’t necessarily mean miracles/signs can’t be a sign of holiness. Otherwise the ministry of Jesus is basically inconsequential in telling us who he is till he dies for our sins. Jesus himself rebukes those who accuse him of healing and casting out demons by the power of Satan.

Comment: @LukeHill How would someone distinguish a miracle or sign being from that of God or of Satan? It is why having faith alone is so important during God's Eph 3:2 dispensation of grace.  Romans 8:24 "For we are saved by hope: but hope that is seen is not hope: for what a man seeth, why doth he yet hope for?"

Comment: @MarkVestal the telltale sign is presented in 1st John, does the person deny that Christ has come in the flesh? If he has, he is an antichrist. Thus, if the person upholds Christ has come in the flesh we can make this distinguishment. 1st John is very clear on this point.

Comment: @LukeHill Yes, he is clear, but he is speaking directly to Jews who are enduring the tribulation, and who also require signs (1 Cor 1:22). He is not speaking to you or I.  Recall that Christ on earth was a minister to the circumcision (Rom 15:8), but you and I are to follow Christ ascended through Paul, where our conversation is in heaven, not earth (Phil 3:17-20).   2 Cor 5:16 "Wherefore henceforth know we no man after the flesh: yea, though we have known Christ after the flesh, yet now henceforth know we him no more."  Hebrews through Revelation are for our learning, but written to the Jews.

Comment: @MarkVestal this is simply false, John is addressing Christians who were dealing with Gnosticism. He refers to the receivers of his letters as “anointed”. We know they aren’t Jews because Jews reject the coming of Christ in the flesh.

Comment: @LukeHill John 4:22
"Ye worship ye know not what: we know what we worship: for salvation is of the Jews."  Peter's church at Pentecost was Jew only. They were to be the beginning of Israel's nation of priests. Acts 11:19
"Now they which were scattered abroad upon the persecution that arose about Stephen travelled as far as Phenice, and Cyprus, and Antioch, preaching the word to none but unto the Jews only." However, because Israel 'as a nation' rejected Christ, salvation became available to the whole world...without first having to go through Israel "to provoke them to jealousy" (Rom 11:11).

Comment: @MarkVestal you haven’t made a point. The fact is that Jesus commissions the disciples to preach to the whole world, and reveals to Peter (in vision and by Cornelius’ receiving of the Holy Spirit) that salvation is just as much for the gentiles as Jews. Further, there is a distinction between the “Jewish religion” and the Jewish people. 1 John is not written to the Jewish religion. It is written to Christians.

Comment: @LukeHill It is Paul that states John went to Jews: Gal 2:7-9 "But contrariwise, when they saw that the gospel of the uncircumcision was committed unto me, as the gospel of the circumcision was unto Peter; 8 (For he that wrought effectually in Peter to the apostleship of the circumcision, the same was mighty in me toward the Gentiles:) 9 And when James, Cephas, and John, who seemed to be pillars, perceived the grace that was given unto me, they gave to me and Barnabas the right hands of fellowship; that we should go unto the heathen, and they unto the circumcision." Paul went to Gentiles (us).

Comment: @MarkVestal you’re distorting the scriptures by ignoring them in totality. The council of Jerusalem (presided over by John) dictates that the gospel is for the gentiles and that these gentiles don’t need to be circumcised. Paul removes the distinction of Jew and Greek in Christ Jesus. You are removing the Bible from its complete historical-doctrinal development.

Comment: @LukeHill Actually, I am "rightly dividing" as we are commanded to do when studying.  The contradictions and confusion ceases when viewed in this proper context.  2 Tim 2:15 "Study to shew thyself approved unto God, a workman that needeth not to be ashamed, rightly dividing the word of truth."  Israel awaits her future earthly kingdom to come.  You and I, however, are blessed with all "spiritual blessings in heavenly places", not earthly. Eph 1:3 "Blessed be the God and Father of our Lord Jesus Christ, who hath blessed us with all spiritual blessings in heavenly places in Christ:)"

Comment: @LukeHill Israel, and the church, the body of Christ, are both "in Christ" and will come together at the full of times: Eph 1:10 "That in the dispensation of the fulness of times he might gather together in one all things in Christ, both which are in heaven, and which are on earth; even in him:"  Israel is God's earthly body of believers.  We are God's heavenly body of believers.  These are indeed two separate entities with two very distinct purposes.  Every believer today is filling the church, which is Christ's body, but Israel must still receive her earthly kingdom as promised in the OT.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152127/discussion-between-luke-hill-and-mark-vestal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Do miracles associated with the cause for canonization have to be believed?**

The short answer is **no**. Ultimately the only person who needs to accept a miraculous event as a miracle is the Supreme Pontiff!

Although the pope can and occasionally has waved the necessity of a miracle required for a canonization, the Supreme Pontiff generally follows the status quo for a recognized miracle before advancing to the actual canonization.

Although official canonizations are deemed infallible by the Church, the miracles accepted by the Holy Father do not share that same privilege.

Some argue that only a certain amount of infallibility is involved here because faith and morals or not directly involved.

> But there are several things unexplained in your piece. The Pope is infallible in matters of faith and morals. The canonization, much less the miracle that supports it, cannot be a matter of faith because that refers to Revelation, and the period of Revelation is over: There is nothing more to be revealed before Jesus returns. So it must be under morals that his infallibility lies. I have for some time felt that this exercise occurs when he declares a man or woman to have lived a life of heroic virtue. It would, it seems to me, be scandalous to encourage people to imitate and pray to someone who did not fit that description. The further stages, I would say, are based on God's verification that the person's cult is influential. You do not mention in your piece whether your statements are official Church teaching or, like my explanation above, your understanding of the process, which is bound to be more knowledgeable than mine. Obviously, if the Pope uses the word 'define,' that suggests his exercise of this authority, but you did say it was an approximate translation."
>
> The 1967 New Catholic Encyclopedia discusses the theological foundation for the infallibility of canonization: "The dogma that saints are to be venerated and invoked as set forth in the profession of faith of Trent (cf. Denz. 1867) has as its correlative the power to canonize. ... St. Thomas Aquinas says, 'Honor we show the saints is a certain profession of faith by which we believe in their glory, and it is to be piously believed that even in this the judgment of the Church is not able to err' (Quodl. 9:8:16).
>
> > "The pope cannot by solemn definition induce errors concerning faith and morals into the teaching of the universal Church. Should the Church hold up for universal veneration a man's life and habits that in reality led to [his] damnation, it would lead the faithful into error. It is now theologically certain that the solemn canonization of a saint is an infallible and irrevocable decision of the supreme pontiff. God speaks infallibly through his Church as it demonstrates and exemplifies its universal teaching in a particular person or judges that person's acts to be in accord with its teaching."
>
> A further argument can be offered. With a canonization, the Pope mandates (rather than permits, as is the case of beatification) that a saint be venerated in the Church's liturgy and especially with the Eucharistic celebration in his honor. Considering that the Mass is the highest and most perfect form of worship, it is logical that the Holy Spirit would guard the Pope and the Church from any error regarding a canonized person's definitive state. At the same time, it must be recognized that this is an argument based on congruence and is not apodictic. The institution of a liturgical celebration does not in itself imply an exercise of infallibility.
>
> [Canonizations and Infallibility](https://www.ewtn.com/catholicism/library/canonizations-and-infallibility-4590)

Only the pope can pronounce someone in heaven through a decree of canonization; thus it is fitting that only the pope needs to be convinced that a genuine miracle has occurred.

> Before someone can be canonized as a saint, the **Vatican’s Congregation for the Causes of Saints must be presented with evidence of a second posthumous miracle**. This miracle must be verified before the canonization can proceed and it must have occurred after the candidate’s beatification.
>
> This final step to sainthood is not taken lightly — canonization is considered to be an infallible act of the pope. That explains the rigorous process — there cannot be errors in the selection of saints. Sainthood is not revocable — there are no "former" saints. - [The road to Catholic sainthood, a miracle at a time](https://www.cbc.ca/news/world/the-road-to-catholic-sainthood-a-miracle-at-a-time-1.995696)

Throughout the complex investigation of someone canonization process it is ultimately the pope and the pope alone who must be convinced to advance to the next step. This is why each miracle has to be throughly investigated; not only only by a number of Cardinals, but also by a number of medical professionals and advisors. It is this group that makes the recommendation to the Holy Father as to whether they believe a miracle has occurred or not **by means of a vote**!

Their vote, regardless of the outcome is always presented to the pope. After all he makes the ultimate decision.

> Most proposed miracles often fall under the medical miracle category. While the world is full of many unexpected medical recoveries, for the Church to determine an event to be a miracle, it must be instantaneous, spontaneous and complete, leaving physicians without a scientific or natural explanation to what has occurred. Someone making an unexpected recovery from a potentially terminal illness would be an unforeseen and splendid sign of God’s love. However, it would only qualify as a miracle if a physician could not treat the patient medically.
>
> While miracles play an important role in the Catholic Church, using them to determine potential sainthood has a relatively short history in the faith. Miracles only became a requirement for sainthood under Pope Gregory IX in 1234. Up to that point, sainthood was largely determined through martyrdom or tradition.
>
> John Paull II also reduced the number of miracles needed for sainthood from three to two miracles. As scientific understanding has grown, medicine and science can now explain many things or events traditionally viewed as miracles. - [Miracles and the Catholic Tradition](https://catholicworldmission.org/miracles-and-catholic-tradition/)

In 2016, Pope Francis somewhat altered the norms

> **New rules**
>
> The process of canonization has undergone continuous revisions throughout history.
>
> In 2016, Pope Francis initiated reforms in how the church assesses miracles, which are meant to make the process more rigorous and transparent.
>
> Another of Francis’ reforms is that in order for a canonization case to go forward, two-thirds of the medical board are required to affirm that the miraculous event cannot be explained by natural causes. Previously, only a simple majority was needed. - [What’s a ‘miracle’? Here’s how the Catholic Church decides](https://dornsife.usc.edu/news/stories/what-is-a-miracle/)

Thus miracles that are proposed as a miraculous support of someone’s holiness is not an obligation of belief, but would rather fit into the category of Marian Apparitions and could be declared **worthy of belief**.

Even the Apparitions of Fatima and the Miracle of the Sun have in themselves been declared **worthy of belief**, even though two seers of Fatima are now saints and the Church has a liturgical feast day for Our Lady of Fatima.

Canonization miracles are **worthy of belief**, not an obligation of belief on the faithful.

Comment: +1 -- But I wonder if the pontiff  needs to positively believe it was a miracle, or whether he could also decide that the preponderance of the evidence (e.g. 2/3 of the medical board voting yes) leads to that conclusion.

Comment: Well put together answer, thanks!